# Proof on undirected graph/ minimal spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have an undirected simple graph $ G=(V,E)$ with $V= \{1,...,n\}$ and $ w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , w(e_{ij}):=i+j$
I want to show, that $ (V,T)=(\{1,...,n\},\{ \{1,2\}, \{1,3\},....,\{1,n\}\})$ is a minimal spanning tree. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on $G$? looks like you need at least al edges $\{1,k\}$ to be present. Is $G$ is the complete graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose edge $e=\{i,j\}$ with $1<i<j$ belongs to a minimal spanning tree.
Verify that the spanning tree must contain either a path from $1$ to $i$ not involving edge $e$ or a path from $1$ to $j$ not involving edge $e$.

In the first case replace edge $e$ by edge $\{1,j\}$, in the second case replace it by edge $\{1,i\}$.
Verify that you still have a spanning tree.

Now you have contradicted the minimality of the original spanning tree.

Comment: How can e belong to T. In T you can only have edges like 1 to i ?

Comment: I *define* $e$ to be the edge between $i$ and $j$. It need not belong to $T$, because we must prove that any other spanning tree is not minimal.

Comment: That's the principle of the proof. Suppose you have a minimal spanning tree $T$. If you have an edges $\{i,j\}$ that is not $\{1,k\}$, than you can find another spanning tree (replacing this edges by $\{1,j\}$ or $\{1,i\}$ ) with weight smaller that $wt(T)$. This is a contradiction to the minimality of $T$. Therefore a minimal spanning trees includes only edges $\{1,k\}$. And Then in order to be a spanning tree, it mus includes all $\{1,k\}, \ k=1,\ldots,n$

Comment: Thank you very much:) That was very helpful:)